# Add the two columns and then multiple rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Below find the sample table.I want to calculate the total population(emp+nemp) of each country.Means i have to add the two columns which  can be easily done and then add the data from multiple rows as well as per the same country name.

This the sample table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
    T.country,
    SUM(T.emp + T.nemp) People
FROM
    YourTable T
GROUP BY
    T.country
```